# String seen as a Monoid

Tags: scala, scalaz

Given a signature like this one or [that one](http://scalaz.github.com/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.2/doc.sxr/scalaz/Iteratee.scala.html#47086):

```
def foo[A, F[_]](implicit mon: Monoid[F[A]], pr: Pure[F]): F[A]
```

Assuming A is `Char`, is there a way to get a `String` instead of a `List[Char]`?

`String` does not take a type parameter, so I assume it's not possible. What's the next best option? Right now, I use `mkString` on the result, but that doesn't feel optimal.

I think `String` is a monoid with *zero* `""` and *append* `+`...

Comment: Why do you need Monoid[F[A]] instead of just Monoid[F]?

Comment: @CheatEx, in this case, I'm not the one who wrote `foo`, I am just the caller.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to persuade String to masquerade as a higher-kinded type, and hence allow functions of the form of `foo` to be applicable. However, Scala's type inference isn't currently up to the job of inferring `foo`'s type arguments, so you'll have to supply them explicitly,

```
// Assuming the the definitions of Pure and Monoid from Scalaz

type ConstString = {
  type λ[X] = String
}

implicit def StringPure = new Pure[ConstString#λ] {
  def pure[A](a: => A) = a.toString
}

val sm = implicitly[Monoid[String]]
val sp = implicitly[Pure[ConstString#λ]]
val f : String = foo[Char, ConstString#λ](sm, sp) // OK
```

Note that the `Char` type argument to `foo` is unused and can be anything, but must be something: in this case either `Char` is the natural choice, but `Nothing` or `Any` would do as well.

Note that this solution trades on `String`'s special characteristics: values of all types are convertible to `String`s so `pure[A](a : => A) : String` is implementable for all types `A`. Replicating this idiom for types other than `String` would most likely have to exploit some mechanism for implementing type-specific cases in the body of `pure` (eg. a pattern match of some sort).

Comment: But `implicitly[Pure[ConstString#λ]].pure('a')` will return the empty String, so this is not really much use. Is it?

Comment: Sure, you'd need a different definition of `Pure[ConstString#λ]` to do any useful work. Answer edited to reflect that.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Indeed you did :-)

Comment: I would suggest `a.asInstanceOf[String]` to reflect the fact that `StringPure` is kinda cheating.

Comment: @retronym Yes, I agree that this is a special case due to `String`'s special characteristics. I've edited the answer to reflect that, but I think that insisting on .asInstanceOf[String] is a bit OTT ;-)

Answer (score 6):

The best solution I can think of it is to define an implicit conversion from `List[Char]` to `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis, that scala's type-system will reject String as not being a "higher kinded type" * -> * is correct. That is, the type String is not assignable to `F[_]` for any F. You could **try** (I have not checked this) implicit conversions...

```
def foo[A, F[_], That](implicit mon: Monoid[F[A]], pr: Pure[F], FA_Is_That: F[A] <%< That)
```

...but this will not be that useful I suspect because you'd have to provide your own bespoke conversions where required but also because the performance would be terrible, assuming this is a hot part of the code.

**Or**, using the standard library, you could use the `CanBuildFrom` machinery but it's far from obvious how *nicely* this will mix with the scalaz-style typeclasses.

```
def foo[A, F[_], That](implicit mon: Monoid[F[A]], pr: Pure[F], b: CanBuildFrom[A, F[A], That]): That
```

In the body of the method, of course, you will need to use the builder to construct the return value, as opposed to the Monoid/Pure typeclasses, rendering them somewhat redundant, I suspect.